# Extracting files out of a huge directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder that is filled with:

- .mp3 files
- Folders that contain mp3 files Folders that contain some
  amount of folders.
- Each sub-directory may or may not have mp3 files.

I need to extract only the mp3 files out of it and save them elsewhere. The problem is that 90% of the mp3 files have spaces in them. So running this particular script does not work:

```
pushd C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\UNSORTED_MUSIC
for /r %%a in (*.mp3) do copy %%a C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\YEAH\"%%~nxa" /y
```

It moves space-less files just fine. But otherwise, it skips the rest. How can I modify my script to work?

Answer (score 1):

```
for /r %%a in (*.mp3) do copy "%%a" C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\YEAH\"%%~nxa" /y
```

Simply quote any string that may contain separators like spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never understood the windows cmd line. ._.